# Android setting new Intent from Activity class

Tags: android

I have class that extends Activity. That has a "Logout" menu options. When I click that it calling logout(context) from another class (not extends from Activity).

```
public class MyTask extends Activity{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.listlayout); 
}  
   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
   {
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.mytaskmenu, menu); 
return true;
   }   
   @Override 
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) { 
       switch (item.getItemId()) { 
           case R.id.logout: 
               Functions.logout(getBaseContext());
               return true; 
           default: 
              return true; 
        } 
    } 
}


 public class Functions {

    public static void logout(Context context)
    {
        DbAdapter_User db2= new DbAdapter_User(context);
        db2.open();
        db2.handleLogout();
        db2.close();
        context.startActivity(new Intent(context, LogIn.class));
    }
```

And the error is

```
android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: 
Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the         FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
```

WHAT IS GOING WRONG?

Comment: In MyTask class or in Function ?

Comment: passing "this" instead of getBasecontext worked for me. Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the context of the MyTask activity in the functions class, by passing the context of the activity, instead of passing `Functions.logout(getBaseContext());` try `Functions.logout(this.getContext());`

Comment: DO I need to change logout(Context context) in Function ?

Comment: No, just change the parameter of the method, from getBaseContext() to this.getContext()